# query MySQL data from multiple tables with multiple entries with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm working on a database for monitoring sportinjuries. I have 2 tables, one is called injury the other one injury_list.

Injury looks like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
injury_id | name   | body_part  | first_mention | last_changed | status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   2     |  Ben   |   arm      |   2013-06-08  |   2013-06-13 |   0  |
|   3     |  Rick  |   knee     |   2013-05-10  |   2013-06-12 |   0  |
|   4     |  Esther|   ankle    |   2013-05-26  |   2013-06-12 |   1  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and then we have injury_list which I use to store the updates from Physiotherapists and coaches

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  list_id | injury_id | Comments               | trend | comment_added
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1     |     2     | Complains a lot wo.... |   1   |   2013-06-01 |
|   2     |     2     | Gets a little bit be.. |   3   |   2013-06-08 |
|   3     |     2     | no changes so far..... |   2   |   2013-06-13 |   
|   4     |     4     | aches a lot, send t... |   1   |   2013-06-01 |
|   5     |     4     | Got a lot worse ne.... |   1   |   2013-06-08 |
|   6     |     4     | no changes so far..... |   2   |   2013-06-13 |   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Trend is used to show if the injury got worse (1), better(2) or no change(3)

I have an overview off all injuries where I only use the INJURY table and a detailed page per injury, where I use information from both tables this all works fine.

now I want the TREND to show on the main page in the overview, and as you can understand I only want the latest trend (based on comment_added). I tried several several queries but I can't seem to understand how to righteously call the data.

I'm not realy good with joins, and I actually don't know if that is the solution here, I hope someone can help me out:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"
SELECT b.injury_id 
     , bl.injury_id b.name
     , b.body_part
     , b.first_mention
     , b.last_changed
     , b.status 
  FROM injury b
  JOIN injury_list bl 
    ON bl.injury_id = b.injury_id 
 ORDER 
    BY status ASC
     , last_changed DESC;
");
```

thanks in advance for thinking with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...and here's a third way, a simple `LEFT JOIN` to find the latest row to eliminate the subquery;

```sql
SELECT i.*,il1.*
FROM injury i
JOIN injury_list il1
  ON i.injury_id = il1.injury_id
LEFT JOIN injury_list il2
  ON i.injury_id = il2.injury_id
 AND il1.comment_added < il2.comment_added
WHERE il2.injury_id IS NULL
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0d33/3).

EDIT: A quick (and, I realize not entirely easy to follow) explanation; The first join is a totally normal join to get an `injury` and a corresponding entry in `injury_list`. I then `LEFT JOIN` to `injury list` again to *see if there exists a newer entry*. If not, the left join will leave all fields in `il2` NULL (ie, non existant) and we should show the row we just built. If there exists a newer entry, the fields in `il2` will have the data from the newer entry, and in that case the row should not be shown.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me out, the sad thing is I don't understand a thing of what you did here. The fiddle showed me all i wanted to know. So copy pasted and worked!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method...

```
SELECT i.*
     , x.* 
  FROM injury i
  JOIN injury_list x 
    ON x.injury_id = i.injury_id
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT injury_id
            , MAX(list_id) max_list_id 
         FROM injury_list 
        GROUP 
           BY injury_id
     ) y 
    ON y.injury_id = x.injury_id 
   AND y.max_list_id = x.list_id;
```

Comment: thanks Strawberry for thinking with me! I ended up picking the one from Joachim Isasksson.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by matching to a subquery that gets the latest `comment_added` for each `injury_id`.

```
SELECT
  b.injury_id, bl.injury_id b.name, b.body_part,
  b.first_mention, b.last_changed, b.status
FROM injury b
INNER JOIN injury_list bl ON b.injury_id = bl.injury_id
WHERE (bl.injury_id, bl.comment_added) IN (
  SELECT injury_id, MAX(comment_added)
  FROM injury_list
  GROUP BY injury_id)
ORDER BY status, last_changed DESC
```

Comment: This is OK, but note that in most cases an uncorrelated subquery will give better performance.

Comment: But the subquery in my answer *is* non-correlated, isn't it? It doesn't reference the outer query at all.

Comment: Yes, but it's not an "uncorrelated subquery" :-) - it's an IN clause, which is just about the worst thing you can do (although, to be fair, all these things are now blisteringly fast!)

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to look up "uncorrelated" vs "non-correlated" - always something else to learn, which is good, kinda, I guess :)

Comment: @Strawberry, is the answer you provided above an example of an "uncorrelated subquery"? If so, I get it. I use that approach (with a `LEFT JOIN` and a NULL check) to avoid `NOT IN` but I didn't think you needed to be so careful to avoid `IN`. Still, I like it!

Comment: It sure is - [as the manual will testify...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)